# using !duplicated() on multiple columns

Tags: r, duplicates

I am using the duplicated() function in R to find samples with duplicate entries in 3 columns

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("1","2","3"), Lastname = c("Brown", "Wright", "Brown"), Firstname = c("Bob", "Jo", "Bob"), DOB = c("10/10/1970", "08/08/1980","10/10/1970"))
```

I want to get entries where Lastname, Firstname and DOB match or are duplicate

```
test <- df[duplicated(df[c('Lastname', 'Firstname', 'DOB')]),]
```

I am only returning one duplicate not both duplicates

```
ID  Lastname    Firstname   DOB
3   Brown   Bob 10/10/70
```

I want to return ALL entries that are duplicated I would expect

```
ID  Lastname    Firstname   DOB
1   Brown   Bob 10/10/70
3   Brown   Bob 10/10/70
```

Comment: You want only ID 3 not ID 1? You can try `duplicated(..., fromLast = TRUE)` perhaps.

Comment: I want ID 1 and 3 removing 2

Comment: Ok, then the idiom is (strangely) two duplicated calls as covered in the link.

Comment: I have edited the post, to reflect what I want to return.

Comment: read the post that this was marked duplicate of.